# POM for javax:javaee-web-api is invalid, POM in html not xml

Tags: java, maven

My project stopped building as of recently without making me making any changes, I use a few repos in the POM but I want to work from this one as the rest are private. I'm assuming the issue is the same between them all as they all throw the same error.

Netbeans throws this warning on clean/build:

```
The POM for javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

Then follows with a tonne of reading errors like this:

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
error reading C:\Users\TakaI\.m2\repository\javax\javaee-web-api\7.0\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar; error in opening zip file
```

I tried running 'mvn dependency:tree -X' in the console to see more about the error and it tells me this:

```
[WARNING] The POM for javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\TakaI\.m2\repository\javax\javaee-web-api\7.0\javaee-web-api-7.0.pom: unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <!d... @1:3)  @ line 1, column 3
```

which lead me to look into that file and it ended up being html not xml.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--

 Copyright 2018-present Sonatype, Inc.

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.

-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Google Analytics -->
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-101097570-3', 'auto');
  </script>
  <!-- End Google Analytics -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#336699"/>
  <meta name="Description" content="The Search Engine for The Central Repository">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>
  <title>The Central Repository Search Engine</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=3">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.f7f5320423dffda3a3da.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.8f18a0f9e415d58eb479.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.41a14a4e45f97a1f685c.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d02503b84ed5e16f5ee0.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

here is my project pom if that helps (some parts censored):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>xxx-api</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://search.maven.org/</url>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            xxx
        </repository>

        <repository>
            xxx
        </repository>

        <repository>
            xxx
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- xxx Framework. -->
        <dependency>
            xxx
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            xxx
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            xxx
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What can I do to fix this? How do I make it retrieve the pom not this html content?

EDIT:
I have tried deleting the .m2 folder and rerunning everything, it didn't help.

Comment: I you keep getting HTML POM's again and again, there's probably something wrong with you connection (i.e. proxy?) or web settings. I never configured repos in a POM, so double check those `xxx` too.

Comment: @watery it's really silly because it's getting the libraries themselves fine meaning the connection should be fine. I'm completely stumped

Comment: Try `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` as Central Maven Repo URL

Comment: @watery I love you, thank you so much. post that as an answer and ill mark it